# When is a subgroup equal to its "parent" group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with $|G| = n$. Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|H| = n$. Can we conclude that $H = G$? I think we can establish a bijection mapping elements of $H$ to elements of $G$ since every $x \in H$ is also in $G$ and the groups have the same order, but I don't know if this is sufficient to show that the two groups are the same.

Comment: As $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, every element of $H$ is in $G$. Now can you find an element in $G$ that is not in $H$?

Comment: Note that this is true for finite groups. But for infinite groups it is not true - the even numbers are an additive subgroup of the integers. So your argument to establish a bijection will have to use finiteness in some non-trivial way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, in particular it is a subset of $G$. Therefore every element of $H$ is an element of $G$. So $H \subseteq G$.

Can $G$ have some element $x$ that is not in $H$? If so, then $|H \cup \{x\}| = |H| + 1$ since $H$ is finite, and $H \cup \{x\} \subseteq G$. This means that $|H| + 1 = |H \cup \{x\}| \leq |G|$. But this contradicts $|H| = |G|$. So in fact every element of $G$ is also in $H$. In other words, $G \subseteq H$ and therefore $G = H$.